# What is the proper way to use static variable in OOP?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm working on Employee Management System. Each employee belong to one department, when employee logged in to system I store UserId and DepartmentId in my class as below

```
internal static class MyStaticData
{
    internal static Guid UserId { get; set; }
    internal static Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

When user go to create leave application page and hit save button, I need to send both UserId and DepartmentId to store in database, so what is the proper way to send UserId and DepartmentId to this page between

```
// Create instance property inside the class and assign it when create new object.
public class LeavePage
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

var leavePage = new LeavePage { UserId = MyStaticData.UserId, DepartmentId = MyStaticData.DepartmentId };
```

or

```
// Don't have instance property inside the class but use MyStaticData directly
public class LeavePage
{
    public void Save()
    {
        Db.Save(data, ..., MySataicData.UserId, MyStaticData.DepartmentId);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure which one is better (less coupling) or does it has better way to do this?

Comment: You talk about "leave page". Are you developing a web application? Then static user data is a bad idea.

Comment: Are you confusing static object class members with constant instance members? Static members are shared between all instances of of your class. You probably want to use a private const for UserId and DepartmentId since they are variable between users.

Comment: @DanielB: This is Window Application.

Comment: @DanielB: Why static user data is a bad idea ?

Comment: @Akram Shahda: In a web application (asp.net) static variables are shared across the application and have no request scope, so every user will override the static var for others with its own data.

Comment: @Daniel: Right, you meant using static data in this particulary case is bad ..

Comment: @Till: If user go to "Request Training Page" I also need both UserId and DepartmentId when I store data in database. I created MyStaticData class to keep both of them so when I need those value I can get directly from this class or set it to instance property when I create class instance as asked in this question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try using a static instance of some more general class - something like this:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

public static class SessionContext
{
    public static User CurrentUser { get; set; }
}
```

Then use SessionContext.CurrentUser when saving.

Of course, in this case using a static class is probably inappropriate, and you should look into a session-specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no need to include instances of your values in your class, do not do it.